# Risk Premium for Prospect Theory-like value function

Tags: utility, preferences, risk, risk-aversion

I am curious how to calculate the following risk premium for a utility function that is not linear in $w$. What i'm asking is the following:

Consider an agent with utility function $u$, initial wealth $\omega_{0}$, and a zero-mean random variable $\tilde{x}$ that pays $+k;-k$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. Lets further assume that the agents utility function is defined as:

$$u(w)=a*w \text{   for  } w<w_{0} $$ and

$$ u(w)=a*w_{0}+b(w-w_{0}) \text{   for  } w\geq w_{0}$$ where $b<a$

By definition of the risk premium $\pi$, we have

$$ Eu(w+\tilde{x}) = u(w-\pi). $$

By rearranging and given the information above, i can easily solve for $\pi=k/2(1-b/a)$. My question is: How to derive $\pi$ if the utility function is not linear in w, e.g. of the form:

$$ a(w)^\alpha \text{   for  } w<w_{0} $$
and
$$ u(w)=a*(w_{0})^\alpha+b(w-w_{0})^\alpha \text{   for  } w\geq w_{0}$$ where $b<a$ and $\alpha<1$? Thanks a lot

Comment: It would follow the same step as the (piecewise-)linear case, only with an uglier solution.

Comment: @HerrK. Thanks for your comment on this. What do you mean by "uglier"? If i solve for $\pi$ i get something that looks like this: $\pi=w_{0}-(\frac{{ap(w_{0}-k)^\alpha}-(p-1)(aw_{0}^{\alpha}+bk^{\alpha})}{a})^\frac{1}{\alpha}$ where $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's what I got